# Array de palabras extraidas de un texto en C++

Tags: c++, array, string

Estoy intentado hacer una funcion de ordenar alfabéticamente las palabras de un `string`. Para ello, de un `string` tipo texto ejemplo: `"la casa es amarilla"`, debo separar cada palabra por separado `"la"`, `"casa"`, `"es"`,  `"amarilla"` y recién ahí meter esa palabras a un arreglo para después poder ordenarlas alfabéticamente. La parte de ordenar aún no he llegado, pero no logro separar cada palabra del texto y meterla a un arreglo. El `while` es lo que me separa usando los espacios, pero me toma error en `"cin>>palabras[i]"` que dice: ningún operador `"[]"` coincide con estos operandos. Quizá sea algo especifico de la librería `sstream`.

Este es mi intento:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string lectura;
    string cadena= "La casa es amarilla";
    string palabras[10];
    stringstream input_stringstream(cadena);

    while(getline(input_stringstream,lectura,' ')){
        cin>>palabras[lectura];
    }
}
```

Comment: Se supone que una posición de un arreglo es un número, no un `string`.

Answer (score 0):

> me toma error en `"cin>>palabras[i]"`

Ese no es el código que has publicado, en el código que compartes estás indexando la formación `palabras` con la variable `lectura`. Las formaciones se deben indexar con números pero `lectura` no lo es:

```
string lectura;
```

Probablemente querías hacer esto:

```
int main() {

    string cadena = "La casa es amarilla";
    string palabras[10];
    stringstream input_stringstream(cadena);

    for (int i = 0; input_stringstream; getline(input_stringstream, palabras[i],' '), ++i);

    for (const auto &p : palabras)
        cout << p << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5LTsNADN3PKZ5aiSRqkMqWhJ6AG0CFzGSILE08o/msKs4eJgTRIOqFLT/7fbT399qSjPO8Z9E2DwY9u5iCoemkrli8AaXAMp6UyrFMCE0metIGMQ2dUiwJE7HUDS5KodRKgKbBCOEJu2cqSySYCJoosLW067avniy9B4ovD8fz9rCGAYvP6W0L1at4062OHy6gXoJwsTt2NwgdRpMsi6n/39qrP5/bClXT4nDgP@LaSUygnBzuPB5/Gc33y1La5YS@h19a9SrVDz2YlIOUVOpznr8A)</kbd>.

Si te fijas, no estamos indexando `palabras` para leerlas por consola (`cin` es la consola: *`c`onsole `in`put*) si no que directamente las leemos del *stream* en la posición que corresponda.